# Separability and open balls

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, weak-convergence

I have a super basic question that for some reason has been eluding me for quite a while. This question actually came up in the context of weak convergence of probability measures on the space $D[0,1]$.

> In a non-separable metric space, is it ever possible to
>   find an open ball such that both the open ball **and its
>   complement** are not separable?

I've phrased it this way because my gut feeling is that there are cases where it is possible, but I suppose it may very well never be possible. Can anyone give some tips about how to prove or disprove this?

**EDIT:** My original formulation of the question was "is it always possible to find..." As Brian M. Scott pointed out below, the answer is in the negative (e.g. uncountable space with discrete metric). But, it is sometimes possible? Is it never possible? Is there an easy example to either effect?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: let $X$ be an uncountable set with the discrete metric

$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0,&\text{if }x=y\\1,&\text{if }x\ne y\end{cases}$$ for all $x,y\in X$. Let $x\in X$ be arbitrary; then $B(x,r)=\{x\}$ if $0<r\le 1$, and $B(x,r)=X$ if $r>1$. In the first case the ball is separable, and in the second case its complement is separable.

**Added:** Let $Y=X\times\{0,1\}$. For $i\in\{0,1\}$ let $X_i=X\times\{i\}$, and define a metric on $Y$ as follows:

$$d(\langle x,i\rangle,\langle y,j\rangle)=\begin{cases}
d(x,y),&\text{if }i=j\\
2,&\text{if }i\ne j\;,
\end{cases}$$

where $d$ is the discrete metric on $X$ given above. Let $p=\langle x,i\rangle\in Y$; then $B\left(p,\frac32\right)=X_i$ and $Y\setminus B\left(p,\frac32\right)=X_{1-i}$ are both non-separable.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I now realized I phrased my question incorrectly. I'm actually more interested in examples where I *can* find such an open ball. So sorry for the mix-up! I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: @gogurt: I’ve added an example in which every point is the centre of a non-separable open ball whose complement is non-separable.

Comment: This answer is perfect. Simple yet illuminating. Thanks Brian!

Comment: @gogurt: You’re welcome!